# Karate Api Testing with Maven and Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins, karate

I am using karate default arche type as mentioned in the karate tutorial and running testing successfully with cucumber reports using Eclipse but when i use the same project in Jenkins i am getting following error. 
I am using Java 1.8 and Cucumber-reporting tool, Please help me solving this issue as i suspect this is issue with the project structure

```
    <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f D:\CogsdaleWorkspace\karate-archetype\pom.xml clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.mycompany:myproject >-----------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\CogsdaleWorkspace\karate-archetype\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\CogsdaleWorkspace\karate-archetype\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 10 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\CogsdaleWorkspace\karate-archetype\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/CogsdaleWorkspace/karate-archetype/src/test/java/nexusportalapi/TestParallel.java:[3,24] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/CogsdaleWorkspace/karate-archetype/src/test/java/nexusportalapi/TestParallel.java:[3,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /D:/CogsdaleWorkspace/karate-archetype/src/test/java/nexusportalapi/TestParallel.java:[11,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/CogsdaleWorkspace/karate-archetype/src/test/java/nexusportalapi/TestParallel.java:[34,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class nexusportalapi.TestParallel
[INFO] 4 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.046 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-12-18T07:25:48-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project myproject: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /D:/CogsdaleWorkspace/karate-archetype/src/test/java/nexusportalapi/TestParallel.java:[3,24] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/CogsdaleWorkspace/karate-archetype/src/test/java/nexusportalapi/TestParallel.java:[3,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
[ERROR] /D:/CogsdaleWorkspace/karate-archetype/src/test/java/nexusportalapi/TestParallel.java:[11,17] package org.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /D:/CogsdaleWorkspace/karate-archetype/src/test/java/nexusportalapi/TestParallel.java:[34,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class nexusportalapi.TestParallel
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

POM FILE

`http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <karate.version>0.9.4</karate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>


</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to tell with just this info, can you try 2 things:

- upgrade to Karate version `0.9.5.RC5`
- use the version we have
  tested with for the cucumber-reporting lib: 3.8.0 -
  https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

You are in the best position to troubleshoot this - but you can try follow this process if all else fails: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that as well but still getting same issue

Comment: @SeleniumIsLove see last link above, all the best